# can not open text selection of TextFormField after upgrade to Flutter 1.17.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Flutter **1.17.0**.
I have tested all app and every thing is good but one thing is not good 
when I tap double click in TextFormField to paste text to TextFormField.
I get error:

> �[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe following
>   assertion was thrown building
>   _OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7](dirty,
>   state: _OverlayEntryWidgetState#f2029):�[39;49m No MediaQuery widget
>   found.
>
> �[38;5;244m_OverlayEntryWidget widgets require a MediaQuery widget
>   ancestor.�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe specific widget that could not find a
>   MediaQuery ancestor was:
>   _OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7]�[39;49m
>   �[38;5;244mdirty�[39;49m �[38;5;244mstate:
>   _OverlayEntryWidgetState#f2029�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe ownership chain for the affected widget is:
>   "_OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7] ← _Theatre ← Overlay ← Directionality ← FlutterEasyLoading ←
>   EasyLocalizationProvider ← ScopedModelDescendant ← _InheritedModel ←
>   AnimatedBuilder ← ScopedModel ← ⋯"�[39;49m
>
> �[38;5;248mTypically, the MediaQuery widget is introduced by the
>   MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the top of your application widget
>   tree.�[39;49m
>
> �[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was�[39;49m
>   �[38;5;248mFlutterEasyLoading�[39;49m �[38;5;244mWhen the exception
>   was thrown, this was the stack�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#0
>   debugCheckHasMediaQuery.�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#1
>   debugCheckHasMediaQuery�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#2
>   _MaterialTextSelectionControls.buildToolbar�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#3 TextSelectionOverlay._buildToolbar�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#4
>   _OverlayEntryWidgetState.build�[39;49m �[38;5;244m...�[39;49m �[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════�[39;49m

Comment: It seems like an issue with your `MediaQuery`, not with the `TextFormField`.

Comment: how to solve it with MediaQuery

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116541/double-click-in-textformfield/62197781#62197781