# double click in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

i use flutter 1.17.0
but one thing is not good when i tap double click in TextFormField
to paste text to TextFormField i get this error

> �[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe following
>   assertion was thrown building
>   _OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7](dirty,
>   state: _OverlayEntryWidgetState#f2029):�[39;49m No MediaQuery widget
>   found.
>
> �[38;5;244m_OverlayEntryWidget widgets require a MediaQuery widget
>   ancestor.�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe specific widget that could not find a
>   MediaQuery ancestor was:
>   _OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7]�[39;49m
>   �[38;5;244mdirty�[39;49m �[38;5;244mstate:
>   _OverlayEntryWidgetState#f2029�[39;49m �[38;5;244mThe ownership chain for the affected widget is:
>   "_OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#8f5d7] ← _Theatre ← Overlay ← Directionality ← FlutterEasyLoading ←
>   EasyLocalizationProvider ← ScopedModelDescendant ← _InheritedModel ←
>   AnimatedBuilder ← ScopedModel ← ⋯"�[39;49m
>
> �[38;5;248mTypically, the MediaQuery widget is introduced by the
>   MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the top of your application widget
>   tree.�[39;49m
>
> �[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was�[39;49m
>   �[38;5;248mFlutterEasyLoading�[39;49m �[38;5;244mWhen the exception
>   was thrown, this was the stack�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#0
>   debugCheckHasMediaQuery.�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#1
>   debugCheckHasMediaQuery�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#2
>   _MaterialTextSelectionControls.buildToolbar�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#3 TextSelectionOverlay._buildToolbar�[39;49m �[38;5;244m#4
>   _OverlayEntryWidgetState.build�[39;49m �[38;5;244m...�[39;49m �[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════�[39;49m

**my main.dart**

```
void main() {
runApp(EasyLocalization(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State createState() {
return _MyAppState();
}
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
final MainModel _model = MainModel();

@override
void initState() {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([

]);
_model.initAppDirectory();
super.initState();
}

changeStatusBar() async{
await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(MySetting.mainColor);
FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
if(Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android){
await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarColor(Colors.black38);
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
changeStatusBar();
var data = EasyLocalizationProvider.of(context).data;

return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
    model: _model,
    child: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      rebuildOnChange: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
      return EasyLocalizationProvider(
        data: data,
        child: FlutterEasyLoading(
          child: MaterialApp(
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
              child: child,
              );
            },
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'my app',              
            localizationsDelegates: [
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              EasylocaLizationDelegate(
                  locale: Locale('ar', 'DZ'), path: 'assets/languages'),
            ],
            supportedLocales: [Locale('ar', 'DZ'), Locale('en', 'US')],
            locale: data.locale,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: MySetting.mainColor,
            ),
            home: SplashScreen( _model),
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }));
}
}
```

please any help to solve it
because my app is stoped for solve this problem
and red screen error is still appers 
and i didn't know where the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case, the error was FlutterEasyLoading library.

After remove that library, double click on TextFormField start to work without errors.

I Hope this help you.